# Accessing Component Wrapped By React Hot Loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader, hot-module-replacement

Given the root React component below:

** Notice the react hot loader export statement.

```
class UI extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            message: ""
        };
    }

    displayMessage() {
        this.setState({
            message: "Hello World!"
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.message }
            </div>
        )
    };
} 

export default hot(module)(UI);
```

and my App:

```
import UI from './UI'

class App {
    constructor() {
        this.loadUI();
    }

    loadUI() {
        this.ui = render(
            <UI/>,
            document.getElementById('app')
        )
    }
}
```

How do I get through the hot loader wrapper and access the `displayMessage` method in the `UI` component as in:

```
const app = new App;
app.ui{{ ** Insert Answer ** }}.displayMessage();
```